# Rails 2.x server failing to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby on rails 2.x application and am trying to start the local server by running "script -e production" inside of the application's script directory.  I can't seem to get the server to start.  I have uninstalled all of my gems and re-installed them using "bundle install".  None of the following errors actually look fatal to me.  Would somebody be able to shed some light on why the server is failing to load?  The output of my attampting to start the server is as follows:

```
--[dps@neve]-[/tmp/asapnew/asap/script]--
> ./server -e production
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.14 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
config.load_paths is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths instead
config.load_paths= is deprecated and removed in Rails 3, please use autoload_paths= instead
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21.
Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard CSV library.  It's FasterCSV plus
support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine.
--[dps@neve]-[/tmp/asapnew/asap/script]--
>
```

**Edit:** Here are my current gem versions (installed by the bundler).

```
--[dps@neve]-[/tmp/asapnew/asap]--
> bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (2.3.14)
  * actionpack (2.3.14)
  * activerecord (2.3.14)
  * activeresource (2.3.14)
  * activesupport (2.3.14)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.3.4)
  * configatron (2.6.3)
  * declarative_authorization (0.4.1)
  * fastercsv (1.5.3)
  * haml (3.0.4)
  * hoptoad_notifier (2.4.7)
  * liquid (2.0.0)
  * memcache-client (1.8.3)
  * mysql2 (0.2.18)
  * newrelic_rpm (2.13.4)
  * nokogiri (1.4.1)
  * paperclip (2.3.1.1)
  * pdfkit (0.5.2)
  * prawn (0.8.4)
  * prawn-core (0.8.4)
  * prawn-layout (0.8.4)
  * prawn-security (0.8.4)
  * preferences (0.4.2)
  * rack (1.1.3)
  * rails (2.3.14)
  * rake (0.8.7)
  * ruby_parser (2.0.6)
  * sanitize (1.2.1)
  * searchlogic (2.4.9)
  * sexp_processor (3.2.0)
  * slim_scrooge (1.0.11)
  * uuidtools (2.1.1)
  * version_bumper (0.3.0)
  * will_paginate (2.3.12)
  * yamler (0.1.0)
--[dps@neve]-[/tmp/asapnew/asap]--
>
```

Comment: Can you post your application.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was arising because of a conflict between the mysql and mysql2 gem. I commented out the mysql2 gem from my Gemfile, and explicitly added mysql; this seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a gem dependency on Rails 3 while trying to use Rails 2. What gems are you using? You might have to dive into each one and get more specific in which version to use (to ensure that it works with Rails 2).

Comment: Hi, Thank-you so much for your response.  I am am having my gems built the bundle installer (somebody else actually wrote this app).  Is there a place where I can speficially define where gems are installed, or at least make a determination on which ones require ruby3?  I have updated my post above to show the gems that automatically get build by the "bundle install" command.

Comment: Is there any way to tell what gems have a dependency on Rails 3?

Comment: Those are deprecation messages.  You are being told that your config options won't work in Rails 3, they are not telling you that Rails 3 is required.  If a gem required Rails 3+, Bundler would fail to resolve the dependency and you would get a pretty clear-cut error.

Comment: Thank-you very much, messick.  I guess this is back to my original question; do you have any idea why the actual server is failing to load?  Do you see any specific message here being fatal?  I can create a new stub app with rails new and it loads fine.  Thank-you so much for your help in my journey.

Comment: Nothing stands out.  Any change you can just upgrade the app to Rails 3?  While some gems might not explicitly require a recent version of Rails, they might blow up the app because they were not tested with such a old version.